# Why can't EMMS play flac files using the mplayer backend?

Tags: emms, music-player

I'm trying to use EMMS with mplayer as its backend. So far, everything works fine, but for some reason, EMMS refuses point-blank to play anything with a .flac extension in my playlist. I've checked the regex EMMS uses for mplayer, and .flac is a viable extension for it. What could be causing this?

For reference, here is my EMMS config:

```el
;;EMMS
(require 'emms-setup)
(require 'emms-streams)
(require 'emms-librefm-stream)
(require 'emms-librefm-scrobbler)
(emms-devel)
(emms-default-players)
(setq emms-source-file-default-directory "~/Music/")
(setq emms-librefm-scrobbler-username "Chuck_Finley") ;not my real name
(setq emms-librefm-scrobbler-password "tequila-miami") ;not my real password
(emms-add-directory-tree "~/Music/")
```

Comment: Quick sanity check: you can play flac files via mplayer on the command line, yes?

Comment: @Dan Yes, mplayer from the command line works without any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it can be helpful to start with a [minimum *working* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please see if this works for you.  It should help debug any other features of your setup that are causing breakage.

`emacs -Q --load emms-init.el` and then **`M-x emms-play-directory RET ~/Music RET`**, where `emms-init.el` is as follows, and where `~/Music/` contains the 0.4 MB .flac test file downloaded from http://www.linnrecords.com/linn-downloads-testfiles.aspx.  My `mplayer` is MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-2ubuntu3.  With all of this in place I hear an annoying but brief tone.

```el
(package-initialize nil)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(unless (assoc-default "melpa" package-archives)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (package-refresh-contents))

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(setq use-package-verbose t)
(require 'use-package)

;;EMMS
(use-package emms
  :ensure t :defer t
  :config
  (progn
    (require 'emms-player-simple)
    (require 'emms-source-file)
    (require 'emms-source-playlist)
    (require 'emms-player-mplayer)
    (setq emms-player-list '(emms-player-mplayer))
    (setq emms-source-file-default-directory "~/Music/")
    (emms-add-directory-tree "~/Music/")))
```

Comment: That seems to work fine.

Comment: Great, if you feel that that solves the problem, please accept the answer, otherwise, if you would like a bit more help tracing the error, please convert the working example into a not-working example with a similar format and update your question :-]